# Make a function only run once (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function

So I'm trying to create a function which changes the 0 slot of an array to an input value. However I want this function to only be able to run once. How do I do this, any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

```
function submitForm() {
    $('#inputForm').submit;
         if ($("#inputValue").val() != inputException) {
              charSetName();
              $("#inputValue").val("");
         }
         $("#inputValue").val("");
     }
function charSetName() {
    var nameSet = false;
    if (nameSet == false) {
        nameSet = true;
        charDetails[0] = $("#inputValue").val();
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "<li id='name''>Name: " + charDetails[0] + "</li>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I was brought here because I needed something similar.
To anyone who comes next time, here was what I eventually did: 
I simply declared a variable with an initial count of 0.
Then every time my function runs, it auto increases. 
The code I want to run once just checks if the count is 1, then it runs. If not, it doesnt.
Like this:

```
let count = 0;
count === 1 ? doSomething : doNothing
count++
```

Does it help?

Comment: Wale, thank you for eventually dropping this code, I'm having a similar problem and your code helped. Thumbs Up

Comment: ^^ Cheers Wale!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I have defined `isFunctionCalled:Boolean` variable for handle it.

```
var isFunctionCalled = false;

function submitForm() {
  $('#inputForm').submit;
  if ($("#inputValue").val() != inputException) {

    if (!isFunctionCalled) {
      charSetName();
    }

    $("#inputValue").val("");
  }
  $("#inputValue").val("");
}

function charSetName() {
  var nameSet = false;
  if (nameSet == false) {
    nameSet = true;
    charDetails[0] = $("#inputValue").val();
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "<li id='name''>Name: " + charDetails[0] + "</li>";
  }

  isFunctionCalled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mind the **executed** variable:

```
var something = (function() {
    var executed = false;
    return function () {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
            // do something
        }
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this.

Just a simple way is to set a flag value.

```
if(flag){
//your code here...
flag = !flag;
}
```

SO, if the value of the flag is 1 at first it will work. Then as the flag value is changed to 0, then the next time it is called, it will not be invoked, as flag is 0.